# Where to handle NullPointerException( in function or in constructor) while unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing

The following is the an illustration of my problem. I am currently not sure of which way to handle the NullPointerException.

```
public class Util
{
   private Map<Integer, String> myMap;

  public Util(Map<Integer, String> myMap)
  {
     this.myMap = myMap;
  }

  public String getVal(Integer region)
  {
     return myMap.get(region);
  }
}


public class UtilTest {

  @Test
  public void testNull() throws Exception{
    Map<Integer, String> myMap = null;
    Util util = new Util(myMap);

    util.getValue(1);
  }
}
```

The code above will give a NullPointerException as expected. My concern is where should I be handling it, in the constructor or in the function itself

In constructor would be as follows

```
  public Util(Map<Integer, String> myMap)
  {
     if(myMap != null)
     this.myMap = myMap;
     else
     this.myMap = new Map<>();
  }
```

In function, it would be something similar to

```
 public String getVal(Integer region)
 {
   if(myMap != null)
   return myMap.get(region);
   else
   return "";
 }
```

Which of these approaches is better and why should I adopt one over the other?

Comment: There is no general "better" in this case. It depends on how you want that code to behave.

Comment: Well do you want it to be valid for an instance to be created with a null reference? Is it useful at that point at all? (I don't see that this is really a testing question at all, to be honest. Decide how you want your class to behave, and you should be able to test that easily enough.)

Comment: It depends on the needs. What is the `Util` purpose. What is the map representing instead of a Map. Could it be null in an instance ? If you accept a Util to have a null map, do you have a setter ? (if not, you could put if final).  If you don't have any setter, then what is the result of getValue that you want, throw the exception, return null, .. ? A nullpointer is always depending on the expectation.

Comment: Don't handle NullPointerExceptions in the sense of catching them.  The proper response to an NPE is to debug the problem in your code that caused null to get to that place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be in the Util class because, the function outside should have no understanding around what goes inside the creation of Util class. It can send in any invalid/valid value. The constructor should ensure that it is taking good care of all invalid/valid values.

Other perspective of this would be - if there are n places which creates Util, you would have to write this if-else at all those n-places. Better to have it in constructor only.

Answer (score 1):

Its a matter of opinion.
However, since you have not provided a setter method, I will suggest to do it in constructor.

It is OK to leave without checking in constructor if you plan to provide a setter later ( in case the input is not available at that time).

Lastly, null may be valid input to your code, and you are perfectly fine checking it in getter method and throwing an exception yourself instead of letting the system throw a null pointer.

My thought, if no setter, then throw exception from Constructor. Don't let the program throw null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is nowhere !

If someone calls `new Util(null)`, he's either:

- The guy who writes **testing** code related to this class and he explicitely passed `null` because he's testing another part of the class that doesn't rely on this `Map` so it's fine to allow `null` (because the `Map` will never be invoked).
- The guy who's using this class in **production** code and since it's a mistake to use `null` in production, just let the code throw an NPE later and let the guy who dared to use `null` feel the consequences (aka painful debug).